# How to select elements for react select on modal for selenium

Tags: java, reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog

Following is what I am trying to do:
Project is built with ReactJS, I am using Selenium WebDriver with Java.

1. Click on button (I can do this)
2. This opens a modal, which have react select component.

I want to select an element in this select.

HTML Code:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7">
      <div class="Select kpi-select is-searchable Select--single">
        <div class="Select-control">
          <span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-19--value">
            <div class="Select-placeholder">Select KPI</div>
            <div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">
              <input id="add-kpi-kpi-select" aria-activedescendant="react-select-19--value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;">
              <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 14px; font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div>
            </div>
          </span>
          <span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <div class="Select kpi-select is-searchable Select--single">
        <div class="Select-control">
          <span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-20--value">
            <div class="Select-placeholder">Select Time Period</div>
            <div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">
              <input id="add-kpi-timeperiod-select" aria-activedescendant="react-select-20--value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;">
              <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 14px; font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;">
              </div>
            </div>
          </span>
          <span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Code trials and error stack trace please

Comment: I need a code to select elements from React Select component that is on the Modal.

Comment: Which element you wants to target ? Specify value of that element,

Comment: Alright, so my project uses this - http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/

If you see the first option in there (States), I would like to select "Victoria" from this select. 

AND THIS SELECT IS ON A MODAL.

Comment: Pritam, you not given sufficient HTML, at least need  go up 4 level of current DOM node `<div class="Select-input"`, Please show all HTML of that node.

Comment: @yong, I updated the HTML. Hope this will help.

Comment: @Pritam, The HTML Code your given at second time is too much,  some of them is not related to your question, I remove them, just to give an example what's the exact HTML code we expected.  But in your case, we still miss the HTML code of the expaned options after click the dropdown.  I know how to get that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java code to choose KPI

```
String wantedOption = "wanted KPI";

// click the down arrow to expand options
driver.findElement(By.cssSelecor("div.Select.kpi-select span.Select-arrow")).click();


// select wanted KPT
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.Select.kpi-select div.Select-menu"))
    .findElement(By.xpath(String.format(".//div[text()='%s']", wantedOption)))
    .click();
```

Guide to make options keep expand through add break point on click event:

1. Open Chrome DevTool
2. Switch to `Sources` Tab
3. Follow steps as below shown
   [image]
4. Click on the `Select KPI` dropdown from page
5. You will see a new DOM node `<div class="Select-menu-outer">`
   which holds all options in `Element` Tab

[image]