# How to Select value from auto suggest dropdown in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

**I want to do following scenario.**

1. Open URL https://www.amazon.in/
2. Enter computer in the search box
3. We will see a list of the values in the auto-suggest box
4. Select “ computer keyboard” from the list
5. Click on Find button

Comment: Can you show what you have tried till now?

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: Try with xpath //span[contains(text(),'keyboard')]. Make it dynamic to fetch from data source in-case it is going to vary with respect to test runs.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far , your code and error trials if any ?

Comment: which programming language you prefer

Comment: @palak Code trials please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Java**

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys('computer')        
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='suggestions']/div[.='computer keyboard']")).click();   
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".nav-search-submit input").click()
```

Comment: Thanks, yong. But how did you know  XPath "//div[@id='suggestions']/div[.='computer keyboard]" ? Did you find it in Firebug or Chrome Inspect? Or you wrote it by yourself? I would like to learn the method so I could deal with the similar problem in the future.

Comment: You need to add breakpoint on event through DevTool, Here is a guide in another thread I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506794/how-to-select-elements-for-react-select-on-modal-for-selenium/50510894#50510894

Comment: you can type `compu` into the search box, then open Chrome DevTool and follow guide in above link to choose `Event Listener Breakpoints  -> Mouse -> click`, then click the search box to make the cursor back to the search box, after click, the debugger will open, just click continue until  debugger disappear,  then press Backspace Key to delete the last char `u`, wait a moment the auto-suggestion will display, click on any one. The debugger will come back again, use the element select tool in DevTool to select any suggestion from page, it will lead you to the html code of the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

try using this method

```
/**
 * @Purpose This method will select a value from list of values based on the
 *          value parameter we pass in the method
 * @param element
 *            --> element of the webpage
 * @param value
 *            --> value we want to select
 * @return N/A
 */
public static void selectElementByValue(WebElement element, String value) {
    //log.info("Selecting a value");
    Select selectitem = new Select(element);
    selectitem.selectByValue(value);
}
```